# Using bash read to get full user input

Tags: bash

simple question.

My script is asking user for input and then trying to do something with that input. But when using the `read` command, I only get the first word of the user input (delimited by spaces). This seems to happen whether I input the response with quotations or not. It would be preferable not to require the user to type their message in quotations.

Here's the code:

```
echo "what is your commit message?"
read commitmessage
```

If in put: This is an auto commit or "This is an autocommit"

Bash only understands `$commitmessage` as `"This"`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$commitmessage` should contain the entire string. How are you checking that? What does `echo "$commitmessage"` output after that? (And you don't need quotes (and in fact you don't want them in the user input unless they are part of the message itself).

Comment: `IFS=` will just prevent word-splitting and losing extra spaces (so possibly not a bad thing) but won't actually change whether multiple words are assigned to `commitmessage` in this case.

Comment: can you clarify how to use IFS=

Comment: See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html Search for IFS.

Comment: Gotcha. I just wrote preciesely `$IFS=` at the beginning of the function and it now works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not `read` that's the problem: I bet you're not quoting the variable when you use it

```
$ read -p "message? " msg
message? hello world this is a message
$ echo "$msg"
hello world this is a message
```

When you use the variable, make sure you quote it: `"$msg"`
Otherwise, the shell will split the value on whitespace (or whatever is in $IFS)

An example:

```
$ function first_word { echo "$1"; }
$ first_word "$msg"
hello world this is a message
$ first_word $msg
hello
```